# Is there a way to pass variables across spring service classes?

Tags: java, spring, web-services

We are using Spring REST services, where we have a controller class that is composed of many spring service classes, each responsible for something such as database calls, external rest calls etc. When we post a request to the rest service, we are going through an API gateway where a transaction id is added to the request header. We have a need to log the transaction ID in different areas in our REST API, however I would like to know if there is a construct or paradigm that I can use or follow where I don't have to pass the transaction ID through the method signature in each of my spring service methods. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,

Juan

Comment: parameter is the best technique.  if every one of the composed spring service classes has access to the session (as in they already take a WebRequest or HttpServletRequest parameter) you can add the value to the session or to the existing XxxRequest parameter.  If all the service classes are running in the same VM, you can store values is a shared location; any class that wraps this is likely to be a roll-your-own personal version of the existing HttpSession object.

Comment: @DwB thanks! I will play around with the httpsession and see!